# AWS EC2 : Connection Timed Out - SSH

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, connection-timeout, amazon-ebs, amazon-linux

Unable to connect via SSH to my Amazon Linux AMI, However I am able to connect to other instance with same VPC, security group and key.
These are the system logs, appreciate any help on this.
[image]

```
>     [    0.000000] Linux version 4.14.101-75.76.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-60003) (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat
> 7.2.1-2) (GCC)) #1 SMP Tue Feb 19 18:14:51 UTC 2019
>     [    0.000000] Command line: root=LABEL=/ console=tty1 console=ttyS0 selinux=0 nvme_core.io_timeout=4294967295
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
>     [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fc000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
>     [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.7 present.
>     [    0.000000] DMI: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 08/24/2006
>     [    0.000000] Hypervisor detected: Xen HVM
>     [    0.000000] Xen version 4.2.
>     [    0.000000] Netfront and the Xen platform PCI driver have been compiled for this kernel: unplug emulated NICs.
>     [    0.000000] Blkfront and the Xen platform PCI driver have been compiled for this kernel: unplug emulated disks.
>     [    0.000000] You might have to change the root device
>     [    0.000000] from /dev/hd[a-d] to /dev/xvd[a-d]
>     [    0.000000] in your root= kernel command line option
>     [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
>     [    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x40000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
>     [    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
>     [    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000fbc50-0x000fbc5f] mapped at [ffffffffff240c50]
>     [    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x37088000-0x37feffff]
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000EA020 000024 (v02 Xen   )
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000FC00E2A0 000054 (v01 Xen    HVM      00000000 HVML 00000000)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000FC00DF60 0000F4 (v04 Xen    HVM      00000000 HVML 00000000)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000FC0021C0 00BD19 (v02 Xen    HVM      00000000 INTL 20090123)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000FC002180 000040
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000FC002180 000040
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000FC00E060 0000D8 (v02 Xen    HVM      00000000 HVML 00000000)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000FC00E1B0 000038 (v01 Xen    HVM      00000000 HVML 00000000)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: WAET 0x00000000FC00E1F0 000028 (v01 Xen    HVM      00000000 HVML 00000000)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000FC00E220 000031 (v02 Xen    HVM      00000000 INTL 20090123)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000FC00E260 000033 (v02 Xen    HVM      00000000 INTL 20090123)
>     [    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
>     [    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
>     [    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x3ffde000-0x3fffffff]
>     [    0.000000] Zone ranges:
>     [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
>     [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x000000003fffffff]
>     [    0.000000]   Normal   empty
>     [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
>     [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
>     [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009dfff]
>     [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fffffff]
>     [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000003fffffff]
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
>     [    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 1, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-47
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 low level)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 low level)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 low level)
>     [    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
>     [    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 15 CPUs, 14 hotplug CPUs
>     [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
>     [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009e000-0x0009ffff]
>     [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
>     [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
>     [    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x40000000-0xfbffffff] available for PCI devices
>     [    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on Xen HVM
>     [    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
>     [    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:15 nr_cpu_ids:15 nr_node_ids:1
>     [    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 44 pages/cpu @ffff88803e200000 s140120 r8192 d31912 u262144
>     [    0.000000] PV qspinlock hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
>     [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 257928
>     [    0.000000] Policy zone: DMA32
>     [    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=LABEL=/ console=tty1 console=ttyS0 selinux=0 nvme_core.io_timeout=4294967295
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
>     [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
>     [    0.000000] Memory: 988264K/1048180K available (8204K kernel code, 1920K rwdata, 2768K rodata, 2044K init, 3876K bss, 59916K
> reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
>     [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=15, Nodes=1
>     [    0.000000] Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled
>     [    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 25766 entries in 101 pages
>     [    0.004000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
>     [    0.004000]    RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=15.
>     [    0.004000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=15
>     [    0.004000] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 952, preallocated irqs: 16
>     [    0.004000] xen:events: Using 2-level ABI
>     [    0.004000] xen:events: Xen HVM callback vector for event delivery is enabled
>     [    0.004000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
>     [    0.004000] console [tty1] enabled
>     [    0.004000] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
>     [    0.004000] console [ttyS0] enabled
>     [    0.004000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 30580167144 ns
>     [    0.008000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
>     [    0.024004] tsc: Detected 2400.059 MHz processor
>     [    0.028010] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4800.15 BogoMIPS (lpj=9600312)
>     [    0.040005] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
>     [    0.044020] ACPI: Core revision 20170728
>     [    0.059670] ACPI: 3 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
>     [    0.068038] Security Framework initialized
>     [    0.076206] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
>     [    0.092100] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
>     [    0.112022] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.116007] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.120233] mce: CPU supports 2 MCE banks
>     [    0.124030] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 1024
>     [    0.132003] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 1024, 1GB 4
>     [    0.148005] Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Full generic retpoline
>     [    0.152004] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
>     [    0.160004] Speculative Store Bypass: Vulnerable
>     [    0.173851] smpboot: Max logical packages: 15
>     [    0.176833] x2apic: IRQ remapping doesn't support X2APIC mode
>     [    0.184004] Switched APIC routing to physical flat.
>     [    0.190772] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=0 pin2=0
>     [    0.238435] clocksource: xen: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e4dffb, max_idle_ns: 881590591483 ns
>     [    0.244018] installing Xen timer for CPU 0
>     [    0.248079] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x3f, stepping: 0x2)
>     [    0.252050] cpu 0 spinlock event irq 53
>     [    0.256035] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 63 no PMU driver, software events only.
>     [    0.260056] Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
>     [    0.264304] NMI watchdog: Perf event create on CPU 0 failed with -2
>     [    0.268008] NMI watchdog: Perf NMI watchdog permanently disabled
>     [    0.272202] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
>     [    0.275796] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
>     [    0.276011] smpboot: Total of 1 processors activated (4800.15 BogoMIPS)
>     [    0.280482] devtmpfs: initialized
>     [    0.283941] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
>     [    0.284230] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
>     [    0.288031] futex hash table entries: 4096 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
>     [    0.292282] NET: Registered protocol family 16
>     [    0.296242] cpuidle: using governor ladder
>     [    0.300010] cpuidle: using governor menu
>     [    0.304044] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
>     [    0.308007] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
>     [    0.312456] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
>     [    0.318787] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
>     [    0.320217] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
>     [    0.324021] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
>     [    0.328007] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
>     [    0.332006] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
>     [    0.339182] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
>     [    0.340021] ACPI: (supports S0 S4 S5)
>     [    0.343460] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
>     [    0.344043] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
>     [    0.348445] ACPI: Enabled 2 GPEs in block 00 to 0F
>     [    0.412557] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
>     [    0.416018] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS supports [ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
>     [    0.420033] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
>     [    0.424030] acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
>     [    0.429218] acpiphp: Slot [0] registered
>     [    0.433312] acpiphp: Slot [3] registered
>     [    0.436509] acpiphp: Slot [4] registered
>     [    0.440524] acpiphp: Slot [5] registered
>     [    0.444541] acpiphp: Slot [6] registered
>     [    0.448541] acpiphp: Slot [7] registered
>     [    0.452544] acpiphp: Slot [8] registered
>     [    0.458516] acpiphp: Slot [9] registered
>     [    0.460544] acpiphp: Slot [10] registered
>     [    0.464527] acpiphp: Slot [11] registered
>     [    0.468568] acpiphp: Slot [12] registered
>     [    0.472652] acpiphp: Slot [13] registered
>     [    0.476608] acpiphp: Slot [14] registered
>     [    0.480511] acpiphp: Slot [15] registered
>     [    0.484590] acpiphp: Slot [16] registered
>     [    0.489551] acpiphp: Slot [17] registered
>     [    0.492548] acpiphp: Slot [18] registered
>     [    0.496621] acpiphp: Slot [19] registered
>     [    0.500593] acpiphp: Slot [20] registered
>     [    0.504608] acpiphp: Slot [21] registered
>     [    0.508563] acpiphp: Slot [22] registered
>     [    0.512509] acpiphp: Slot [23] registered
>     [    0.516537] acpiphp: Slot [24] registered
>     [    0.520580] acpiphp: Slot [25] registered
>     [    0.524589] acpiphp: Slot [26] registered
>     [    0.528546] acpiphp: Slot [27] registered
>     [    0.532617] acpiphp: Slot [28] registered
>     [    0.536625] acpiphp: Slot [29] registered
>     [    0.540551] acpiphp: Slot [30] registered
>     [    0.544492] acpiphp: Slot [31] registered
>     [    0.548403] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
>     [    0.552006] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
>     [    0.556005] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
>     [    0.560005] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
>     [    0.564009] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xf0000000-0xfbffffff window]
>     [    0.568008] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
>     [    0.580994] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x10: [io  0x01f0-0x01f7]
>     [    0.584013] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x14: [io  0x03f6]
>     [    0.588009] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x18: [io  0x0170-0x0177]
>     [    0.592013] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x1c: [io  0x0376]
>     [    0.597469] * Found PM-Timer Bug on the chipset. Due to workarounds for a bug,
>     [    0.597469] * this clock source is slow. Consider trying other clock sources
>     [    0.601963] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
>     [    0.617879] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs *5 10 11)
>     [    0.620484] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
>     [    0.624308] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
>     [    0.628273] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs *5 10 11)
>     [    0.659090] xen:balloon: Initialising balloon driver
>     [    0.672470] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
>     [    0.676000] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
>     [    0.676028] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
>     [    0.680005] vgaarb: loaded
>     [    0.684298] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
>     [    0.688228] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
>     [    0.692903] NetLabel: Initializing
>     [    0.696007] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
>     [    0.700005] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
>     [    0.704026] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
>     [    0.708043] HPET: 3 timers in total, 0 timers will be used for per-cpu timer
>     [    0.712018] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0
>     [    0.716006] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 62.500000 MHz counter
>     [    0.722208] clocksource: Switched to clocksource xen
>     [    0.732257] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
>     [    0.735847] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
>     [    0.741239] pnp: PnP ACPI init
>     [    0.743942] system 00:00: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] could not be reserved
>     [    0.749560] system 00:01: [io  0x08a0-0x08a3] has been reserved
>     [    0.755099] system 00:01: [io  0x0cc0-0x0ccf] has been reserved
>     [    0.759542] system 00:01: [io  0x04d0-0x04d1] has been reserved
>     [    0.765628] system 00:07: [io  0x10c0-0x1141] has been reserved
>     [    0.769988] system 00:07: [io  0xb044-0xb047] has been reserved
>     [    0.774201] random: fast init done
>     [    0.802572] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
>     [    0.815571] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
>     [    0.823851] NET: Registered protocol family 2
>     [    0.828295] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
>     [    0.836223] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
>     [    0.842471] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
>     [    0.848377] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.854312] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.865357] NET: Registered protocol family 1
>     [    0.870057] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
>     [    0.874521] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
>     [    0.880434] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
>     [    0.886961] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
>     [    0.900418] Unpacking initramfs...
>     [    1.140068] Freeing initrd memory: 15776K
>     [    1.144270] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
>     [    1.149487] Initialise system trusted keyrings
>     [    1.153120] random: get_random_bytes called from key_alloc+0x209/0x430 with crng_init=1
>     [    1.159656] Key type blacklist registered
>     [    1.164319] audit: type=2000 audit(1621604183.240:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
>     [    1.173559] workingset: timestamp_bits=36 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
>     [    1.181126] zbud: loaded
>     [    1.462923] Key type asymmetric registered
>     [    1.466712] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
>     [    1.471526] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
>     [    1.478219] io scheduler noop registered (default)
>     [    1.482503] xen:grant_table: Grant tables using version 1 layout
>     [    1.488560] Grant table initialized
>     [    1.492864] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
>     [    1.498136] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
>     [    1.532534] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
>     [    1.539067] xen_netfront: Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver
>     [    1.546587] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
>     [    1.557894] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
>     [    1.563616] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
>     [    1.569522] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
>     [    1.578461] rtc_cmos 00:02: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
>     [    1.584470] rtc_cmos 00:02: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
>     [    1.591556] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
>     [    1.597392] NET: Registered protocol family 17
>     [    1.602551] sched_clock: Marking stable (1602191383, 0)->(2508005586, -905814203)
>     [    1.608985] registered taskstats version 1
>     [    1.613380] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
>     [    1.617465] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
>     [    1.724098] xenbus_probe_frontend: Device with no driver: device/vbd/768
>     [    1.733164] rtc_cmos 00:02: setting system clock to 2021-05-21 13:36:24 UTC (1621604184)
>     [    1.740878] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2044K
>     [    1.752090] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 14336k
>     [    1.759007] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2016K
>     [    1.766675] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1328K
>     [    1.788444] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
>     [    1.794113] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.37.0-ioctl (2017-09-20) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
>     [    1.808846] udevd[853]: starting version 173
>     [    1.859269] SCSI subsystem initialized
>     [    1.951311] scsi host0: ata_piix
>     [    1.964023] Invalid max_queues (4), will use default max: 1.
>     [    1.970827] scsi host1: ata_piix
>     [    1.973941] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc100 irq 14
>     [    1.979650] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc108 irq 15
>     [    2.011829] blkfront: xvda: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
>     [    2.026784]  xvda: xvda1
>     [    2.144087] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2399.999 MHz
>     [    2.148782] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2298364cab5, max_idle_ns: 440795214892 ns
>     growroot: NOCHANGE: disk=/dev/xvda partition=1: size=16773086, it cannot be grown
>     [    2.214915] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>     [    2.224557] dracut: Remounting /dev/disk/by-label/\x2f with -o noatime,nofail,ro
>     [    2.232584] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>     [    2.240125] dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/xvda1
>     [    2.273312] dracut: Switching root
>     [    2.321659] random: init: uninitialized urandom read (12 bytes read)
>     image_name="amzn-ami-hvm"
>     image_version="2018.03"
>     image_arch="x86_64"
>     image_file="amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20180811-x86_64.ext4.gpt"
>     image_stamp="cc81-f2f3"
>     image_date="20180811012746"
>     recipe_name="amzn ami"
>     recipe_id="5b283820-dc60-a7ea-d436-39fa-439f-02ea-5c802dbd"
>           Welcome to Amazon Linux AMI
>     Starting udev: [    2.454862] udevd[1570]: starting version 173
>     [    2.518886] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
>     [    2.543884] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
>     [    2.611788] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
>     [    2.615632] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input5
>     [    2.669689] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
>     [    2.678057] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
>     [  OK  ]
> 
>
```

> ```
> Setting hostname localhost.localdomain:  [  OK  ]
>
> Setting up Logical Volume Management: [    3.718097] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
>   WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
> [  OK  ]
>
> Checking filesystems
> Checking all file systems.
> [  OK  ]
>
> Remounting root filesystem in read-write mode:  [    3.759745] EXT4-fs (xvda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
> [  OK  ]
>
> Mounting local filesystems:  [  OK  ]
>
> Enabling local filesystem quotas:  [  OK  ]
>
> [    3.791456] random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (4096 bytes read)
> Enabling /etc/fstab swaps:  [  OK  ]
>
> Entering non-interactive startup
> Starting LVM metadata daemon: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting LVM poll daemon: [  OK  ]
>
> [    3.924597] random: vgs: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
> [    4.010580] NET: Registered protocol family 10
> [    4.018195] Segment Routing with IPv6
> Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
>
> Bringing up interface eth0:  
> Determining IP information for eth0... done.
>
> Determining IPv6 information for eth0... done.
> [  OK  ]
>
> Starting auditd: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting system logger: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting irqbalance: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting rngd: [    5.871299] urandom_read: 1 callbacks suppressed
> [    5.871300] random: rngd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
> Unable to open file: /dev/hwrng
> [  OK  ]
>
> [    5.910283] random: crng init done
> Starting rpcbind: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting NFS statd: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting system message bus: [  OK  ]
>
> Mounting filesystems:  [  OK  ]
>
> Starting acpi daemon: [  OK  ]
>
> Retrigger failed udev events--type=failed is deprecated and will be removed from a future udev release.
> [  OK  ]
>
> Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init-local' at Fri, 21 May 2021 13:36:29 +0000. Up 6.53 seconds.
> Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init' at Fri, 21 May 2021 13:36:29 +0000. Up 6.73 seconds.
> ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++++++
> ci-info:  Device   Up     Address          Mask          Hw-Address    
> ci-info:    lo    True   127.0.0.1      255.0.0.0            .         
> ci-info:   eth0   True  172.31.10.11  255.255.240.0  0a:3b:55:e4:8b:7e 
> ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> ci-info:  Route    Destination     Gateway        Genmask      Interface  Flags 
> ci-info:    0        0.0.0.0      172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         eth0      UG  
> ci-info:    1    169.254.169.254   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.255     eth0      UH  
> ci-info:    2       172.31.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.240.0      eth0      U   
> May 21 13:36:29 cloud-init[2433]: __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'sudo yum install -y
> ```
>
> http...'
> Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 21 May 2021 13:36:30 +0000. Up 7.43 seconds.
> Starting sshd: [  OK  ]
>
> ```
> Starting ntpd: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting sendmail: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting sm-client: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting httpd: [  OK  ]
>
> Starting mongod: [  OK  ]
> ```

Comment: Is the EC2 instance you're trying to reach in a public subnet?

Comment: Use `ssh -vvv ec2-user@IP` and show us what the debug log shows.

Comment: @JackMarchetti Yes, additionally I am able to connect to all other ec2-instances in the same subnet.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein 
Unable to attach complete logs, however here's some of debug logs.
chitti@Chitranjans-MacBook-Air Downloads % ssh -vvv ec2-user@ec2-3-7-73-34.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-7-73-34.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.

Comment: Thanks for you help @JohnRotenstein  problem has been resolved, Please find the solution below.

Comment: Thanks for you help @JackMarchetti problem has been resolved, Please find the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved. Please follow below post to check procedure that was followed. Hope it helps someone else as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67648386/3224357